# Page Freezes When Redirecting User After Form Submit

Tags: php

In php, I collect information from the form and build an email. I then have the following code redirect the user to a page after a 200 response code.

```
// Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        header('Location: https://my.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/a.pdf');
        exit;
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Sever Error");
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt to sumbit a form, Chrome freezes and I have to close the tab. Any explanation for the cause and fix of this issue?

Comment: You're missing an opening if statement

Comment: The snippet here is part of a bigger if statement. But I'll strip off the end anyways.

Comment: If you execute the code directly rather than from a form post do you see any syntax errors?

Comment: Page still freezes. I have no idea why.

Comment: Infinite loop? Try another browser? Call it via CURL from a command prompt?

Comment: Ok I didn't try CURL. Never heard of it, is it some software that runs PHP snippets?

Comment: Change `mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)` to `1` if it didn't freeze then the problem is in your `mail()` function.

Comment: Changed and still is freezing.

Comment: Sounds like the suspect is in `mail()`, specifically the connection to your mail service. Do you see any errors in your apache error logs? Are you using `localhost` or a 3rd party SMTP Server? How is `SMTP` set in your php.ini? Have you successfully used `mail()` before and if not, what does your web host advise for relaying mail?